# How to query select JsonArray from Jsonb field in Postges

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have an issue would need your help. I would like to query select data from JsonArray by id.

1. Table (product)

---

```
id(int4)|         data(jsonb)        |       category__id
```

---

2. Field data contain JsonArray as below

```
  {
  "item": [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "hawai",
          "size": {
              "L": 0.5,
              "M": 0.15,
              "S": 0.25
          },
          "price": 10,
          "rating": 10,
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "koka kola",
          "size": {
              "L": 0.15,
              "M": 0.25,
              "S": 0.35
          },
          "price": 20,
          "rating": 100
    }
 ]
}
```

3. My query

```
select * from product where data->'item'->>'id'=1
```

4. Expected output

[image]

but query result show all record which consists on field "data"
it doesn't match what I prefer. I want only data where id=1

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected output based on your sample data? It's unclear to me if you want to extract matching array elements or if you want to get the whole row where one array element matches

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry I tag wrong version . currently I am using PostgreSQL 12. Related to this issue you know how can I select this by id. Thank

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name now I have updated my question also link my expect output result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `jsonb_path_query_array()`

```
select id, jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.item[*] ? (@.id == 1)'), category_id
from product;
```

This isn't exactly what your picture shows though: it will not include the `"item"` key:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "hawai", "size": {"L": 0.5, "M": 0.15, "S": 0.25}, "price": 10, "rating": 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you:) @a_horse_with_no_name for your answer.

Comment: if no id match then it will return `[]`.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra: yes, what else would you expect? If you write a `where` clause that doesn't match, you don't get rows back either

Comment: True. we will not get any row if put it in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  select id, 
         json_build_object('item',array_to_json(array_agg(item))),
         category_id 
from (
select id, jsonb_array_elements(data->'item') as "item", category_id 
from example ) tab
where cast(item->>'id' as int)=1
group by id,category_id
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2authNRNgAKUpnouqFYJ83/0)